# Send an Email, Authenticating using Azure AD

Tags: azure, email, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an application that needs to be able to send an email when a specific event happens.  This is not an application that has a "user" interacting with it.  Our Admins want me to start using OAuth2 to authenticate this email sending.

Here are the scenarios I have considered and the problems I am running into for each of them:

### Client Credentials Authentication Flow

My initial thought was to authenticate the Azure Application using the Client ID and Client Secret (the Client Credentials Authentication Flow).  Then use the resulting token, I would make the call to send the email.

But when I asked my admin to grant my Application the `Smtp.SendAsApp` scope, he told me that having that scope would allow my application to send an email as if it came from any mailbox in the company.  That is not something we want to grant to this application, nor the developers that would be working on it.  (They could send out emails as if they were the CEO!)  We need the application to be able to send from only a single mailbox.

So for this scenario to work, I need a way for my Azure Admin to limit my application to only one mailbox, but to be able to send email from that mailbox.

### Authorization Code Flow (as a User)

For the next scenario, I thought of creating a service account.  This service account would have a mailbox setup and would be the service account that would send the email.

But the problem with this method is that logging in as a user requires interaction.  The authorization code flow has a step where the user has a web page from the IDP loaded, on this page they are required to put in their username and password.

My application is unattended, so no-one will be able to do this login.

### Summary

I need a way to send emails in my application that does not:

1. Allow the developers access to send emails as if they are the CEO
2. Require a user to login.

Is there a way around either of these issues?

Comment: You can make use of `Mail.Send` permission and generate access token via client credentials flow that does not need user interation. Does this help?

Comment: @Rukmini - `Mail.Send` says it grants permissions to send from *any* mailbox (anyone in the company).  My Azure Admins do not want developers to have access to that kind of permissions.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. It seems like the only option here is to give the Mail.Send permission and then limit the access as per the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access